# How do I use my boosters?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

I was browsing the in-game shop and noticed that it says 'Owned 2', when I was looking at the boosters section.

[image: Two boosters]

No doubt because I played the beta or pre-ordered perhaps, yet I can't find a way to activate it whilst playing the game.

So how do I activate this Short XP Booster whilst playing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this forum thread](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1599859-How-do-you-activate-an-xp-booster), it appears to be activated from your Stats screen:

> i just find u go to the weapons menu then u press RSTICK to see ur stats then u can activate a boost
>
> Can confirm it's from the stats screen, thanks!!

From the comment by @DavidYell, the path to this screen appears to be `Loadout` -> `Stats`.

Comment: Correct - I just validated this. In your stats screen, click on BOOSTERS ACTIVATION, then click on the boost you want to turn on.

Comment: Seems to be Loadout > Stats > Booster activation

Comment: @DavidYell thanks, I updated the answer for completion/accuracy